# geometry column locked in pgAdmin and viewer not showing correctly

Tags: postgresql, postgis, pgadmin

I have a column named 'location' and it is of type geometry in my Postgres db. My table has a primary key, and my location srid is set to 4326. My insertion script contains `st_geomfromtext('POINT(1.300966 103.838473)', 4326)`.

When I click on the viewer (the 'eye' icon) in pgAdmin, the map is not showing and I notice there is a lock icon for my location column in the table. All other columns do not have the lock icon.

**Geometry viewer doesn't show map properly**

[image]

**Location column locked**

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I'm using pgadmin to view the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is with your data. In PostGIS, coordinates are expressed as longitude first, then latitude.

You have inserted a point with **latitude** 103, which is out of the -90;90 domain of validity. How it is represented (or not) by various map viewers is another question (some fails, some will wrap around the earth, some will remove 90 etc), but the result can be considered as artistic.

==> try changing the order:

```
st_geomfromtext('POINT(103.838473 1.300966)', 4326)
```

Comment: Hi! A quick question, is it right to say coordinate pairs in PostGIS are always expressed as *x,y*? Aren't there reference systems where it is somehow foreseen to use *y,x* instead? +1 :-)

Comment: @JimJones not too sure for the "always" statement (instead of "most of the time"), especially since one can define its own projection. It is however for sure the case with common projections such as OP's 4326 or 3857

Comment: Alright! Just to be clear, I wasn't trying to be pedantic with my question :-) I just vaguely recall from my studies that there were cases where coordinate pairs were different than in WGS84.. but its been a while :D

Comment: @JGH You are right! After changing to lng lat, I can now view the map in pgadmin. Thanks!